# Meta query orderby meta_value_num sorting by role first

Tags: wp-query, query, user-roles, meta-query, order

I want all of the results to order by `meta_value_num`, but it's ordering by role first. How do I get them to ignore the role order? Here's my code:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 
    'meta_key' => 'Group',
    'meta_value' => $atts['bc'],
    'role__in'    => ['role1','role2','role3'],
    'orderby' => 'meta_value meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
) );    
$users = $user_query->get_results();
```

I also tried `array_merge` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Note that in `WP_Query` you specify multiple orderby using an array of items, but  the `WP_User_Query` docs don't list arrays as a possible value. This might be because it hasn't been updated, or because it's not supported, I don't know which

Comment: I'm not quite understanding how you mean. Do you mind posting an example?

Comment: `'orderby' => [ 'foo', 'bar', 'etc..' ]`, `WP_Query` expects each value to be a string. You don't just pass a single string with each parameter specified by a space, instead to specify an array of items, you use an array. However, the docs for `WP_User_Query` only say that it accepts a string, which implies it does not support multiple orderby values

Comment: Is there a way around this? Perhaps by hooking with `pre_user_query` ?